# Comparing two files and adding the missing values to a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have one big file(file_new.txt) in which 1 set of attributes and its values  are coming number of times. Now  in some set, some attributes and its values going miss when compare to one sample file (sample.txt) attributes.

Sample.txt

```
apple = 0
black = 0
cat = 0
dog = 0
elephant = 0
```

file_next.txt

```
apple = 6
black = 7
elephant = 8
==============
apple=9
cat = 10
elephant =11
```

Here i am seeking output as below(missing attributes from sample.txt should get added in file_new.txt with value zero)

file_output.txt

```
apple = 6
black = 7
cat = 0
dog = 0
elephant = 8
=============
apple = 9
black = 0
cat = 10
dog = 0
elephant = 11
```

Note =1st and last attribute values are permanent(here apple and elephant)

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN   { FS="[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]s*"; OFS=" = " }
NR==FNR { names[++numNames] = $1; dflt[$1] = $2; next }
/^=+$/  { prtRec(); print }
{ curr[$1] = $2 }
END { prtRec() }

function prtRec() {
    for (nameNr=1; nameNr<=numNames; nameNr++) {
        name = names[nameNr]
        print name, (name in curr ? curr[name] : dflt[name])
    }
    delete curr
}

$ awk -f tst.awk sample.txt file_next.txt
apple = 6
black = 7
cat = 0
dog = 0
elephant = 8
==============
apple = 9
black = 0
cat = 10
dog = 0
elephant = 11
```

or if you don't care about the order of the lines in each output record, it's even simpler:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
BEGIN   { FS="[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"; OFS=" = " }
NR==FNR { dflt[$1] = $2; next }
/^=+$/  { prtRec(); print }
{ curr[$1] = $2 }
END { prtRec() }

function prtRec() {
    for (name in dflt) {
        print name, (name in curr ? curr[name] : dflt[name])
    }
    delete curr
}

$ awk -f tst2.awk sample.txt file_next.txt
apple = 6
elephant = 8
cat = 0
black = 7
dog = 0
==============
apple = 9
elephant = 11
cat = 10
black = 0
dog = 0
```

Comment: getting output like this... 
`awk -f tst.awk sample.txt file_new.txt                                                 apple = 0 = 
black = 0 = 
cat = 0 = 
dog = 0 = 
elephant = 0 = 
===============
apple = 0 = 
black = 0 = 
cat = 0 = 
dog = 0 = 
elephant = 0 =`

Comment: nice use of the `next, `name in curr` and direct `?`, i miss all in mine version.

Comment: @Anamdev It is not possible for the script I posted to produce the output you say it does. To get that output you would need to set `ORS=" = "` or similar. Maybe you copy/pasted my script incorrectly? The other alternative is that there's something wrong with your input files, e.g. they might have trailing control-Ms if they were created on Windows. Use `cat -v` to look for control-Ms and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them if present. Given UNIX text files for input, the awk script I posted is very simple and it WILL produce the output you want (and shown in my answer) with any POSIX awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*' '
   function Feed() {
      for( Key in ToAdd){
         if( ToAdd[ Key] == 1) print Sample[ Key]
          else ToAdd[ Key] = 1
         }
      return
      }
   FNR == NR { Sample[$1]=$0;ToAdd[$1]=1}
   FNR != NR && $0 !~ /^=====/ { ToAdd[ $1]=0; print }
   $0 ~ /^=====/ { Feed(); print }
   END { Feed() }
   ' Sample.txt file_new.txt
```

using:

- associative array for data and counter for data to print or remind to print
- function to avoid twice the same code (before and after the `=====`)

order of file is mandatory

Comment: FYI `$0 ~ /^=====/` can be abbreviated to just `/^=====/` and `$0 !~ /^=====/` to `!/^=====/` (which literally means `!($0 ~ /^=====/)` but it's functionally equivalent).

Comment: thanks, i know this but i ue it to be a bit more explicit like the variable name. Anyway, like often, i appreciate your remark

Comment: Got it. For me, it's just something that slows down my reading of a script because it makes me stop to think about why the code is written that way and try to figure out what the intent is that's different from the default behavior but I could see that it might have some benefit to people unfamiliar with awk reading an answer to their question here. Of course, down that path lies `{ if ($0 ~ /^=====/) { foo } }` instead of just `$0 ~ /^=====/ { foo }` so idk where the line should be drawn...